# OpenAI API: How do I use the ChatGPT plugin in Python?

Tags: python, openai-api, chatgpt-api, azure-openai

I want to use the [OpenAI python package](https://github.com/openai/openai-python). However, I also want to make use of some ChatGPT plugins.

I tried the following with Langchain:

```
tool = AIPluginTool.from_plugin_url("https://scholar-ai.net/.well-known/ai-plugin.json")


llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, streaming=True, model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo-16k-0613")
tools = [tool]

agent_chain = initialize_agent(
    tools, llm, agent=AgentType.OPENAI_FUNCTIONS, verbose=True
)

agent_chain.run("What are the antiviral effects of Sillymarin?")
```

Sadly, I got: `InvalidRequestError: This model's maximum context length is 16385 tokens. However, your messages resulted in 16552 tokens (16455 in the messages, 97 in the functions). Please reduce the length of the messages or functions.`

Is there a way to do it directly via OpenAI or via Langchain? If so, how could I do so?

Answer (score 1):

According to the official [OpenAI forum discussion](https://community.openai.com/t/is-it-possible-to-utilize-a-plugin-with-the-chatgpt-api/141512), plugins aren't available via the OpenAI API, as @logankilpatrick explained:

> Not possible right now, might be in the future but no roadmap.

Although ChatGPT plugins can be used with LangChain. See the official [LangChain documentation](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/tools/chatgpt_plugins).

Klarna example from the documentation:

```
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.agents import load_tools, initialize_agent
from langchain.agents import AgentType
from langchain.tools import AIPluginTool

tool = AIPluginTool.from_plugin_url("https://www.klarna.com/.well-known/ai-plugin.json")

llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0)
tools = load_tools(["requests_all"])
tools += [tool]

agent_chain = initialize_agent(
    tools, llm, agent=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION, verbose=True
)
agent_chain.run("what t shirts are available in klarna?")
```

Comment: many thanks for getting back to me. In fact, this is what I tried already (please have a look at my original question from above, which I edited). If you have an idea how to fix that, it would be terrific.

Comment: @tobias Have you tried setting the `max_tokens` parameter to, let's say, `16000`?

Comment: I added this parameter, but the result was still `InvalidRequestError: This model's maximum context length is 16385 tokens. However, you requested 17952 tokens (1855 in the messages, 97 in the functions, and 16000 in the completion). Please reduce the length of the messages, functions, or completion.
`.